# Html.ActionLink redirects to the current page on a bad route, what causes this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I enter

```
@Html.ActionLink("RealTestingRoute broken link","asdf","Home",new {id = 7},null)
```

In 2 projects, the first being a proper project and the second being a new test project,

The first project renders: localhost:56117/Home/asdf/7 (which is what I want, To reiterate I want the broken link !)

In the second, real, project, it just links back to the main page, so I get : localhost:49550/

That's causing this and how do I stop it, it's preventing us from crawling the site and finding broken links etc...

Comment: Do these two projects have identical routing settings?

Comment: I think you can improve the text of this question is not very clear

Comment: What does your RouteConfig file contain in both projects.  .... What Andrei said...